# what difference between privileges in posgtresql?

Tags: postgresql

new on postgresql DBMS. 
after a `\l` command we have an output similar of this:

```
postgres  | postgres     | UTF8     | it_IT.UTF-8 | it_IT.UTF-8 |
template0 | postgres     | UTF8     | it_IT.UTF-8 | it_IT.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
          |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
template1 | postgres     | UTF8     | it_IT.UTF-8 | it_IT.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
          |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

After I create a role named root and grant it superuser privileges I get this output:

```
postgres  | postgres     | UTF8     | it_IT.UTF-8 | it_IT.UTF-8 |
root      | root         | UTF8     | it_IT.UTF-8 | it_IT.UTF-8 | =Tc/root             +
          |              |          |             |             | **root=C*T*c*/root**
template0 | postgres     | UTF8     | it_IT.UTF-8 | it_IT.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
          |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
template1 | postgres     | UTF8     | it_IT.UTF-8 | it_IT.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
          |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

My question is, what's difference between **CTc** and **C*T*c*** ?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html

Comment: thank's Milen A. Radev !

Comment: I strongly disagree with the close-vote on this question. DBA.SE, sure. (Interesting question, btw, shows a flaw in the documentation).